# Reading vector from launch file does not work in Indigo

Tags: roslaunch, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I'm facing an issue while reading a vector parameter from launch file in ROS Indigo. I set the parameter in my launch file in the private namespace of my node as;

```
<param name="x0" value="[0.0, 0.0]"/>
```

And I'm trying to read it as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Retrieving_Lists) or [in this previous answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/206146/arrays-ros-launch-file/):

```
ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
std::vector<double> x0;
nh.getParam("x0", x0);
```

but if I try to print the size of the vector it tells me 0. From the [roslaunch param documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/param) it seems that parameters which are not scalar numbers or literal booleans are interpreted as strings.

Why is there such inconsistency between the types that I can read from the parameter server and the parameters that I can set from a launch file? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks to all in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291984/reading-vector-from-launch-file-does-not-work-in-indigo/) by [d.fenucci](https://answers.ros.org/users/24372/d.fenucci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2018-05-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-23**:
So just to clarify: does this work if you use:

```
<rosparam param="x0">[0.0, 0.0]</rosparam>
```

**Comment by [d.fenucci](https://answers.ros.org/users/24372/d.fenucci/) on 2018-05-23**:
Yes, in this way it works. Thanks, I didn't notice the comment in the previous answer. Still, is there any reason for this inconsistency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Arrays need to be passed using `rosparam` instead of the normal `param` which is only able to accept scalar values or strings.
The normal `param` has no way to tell the difference between a string and an array so it is always interpreted as a string.
Since `rosparam` expects YAML syntax it is able to handle arrays. It can also handle dictionaries and others things specifiable in YAML syntax.

In your case it would look like this:

```
<rosparam param="x0">[0.0, 0.0]</rosparam>
```

Thanks to @gvdhoorn for answering this in a comment. I tried to expand on it and explain why `rosparam` was needed.

---

Originally posted by [Link](https://answers.ros.org/users/483/link/) with karma: 228 on 2018-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1